# Installing Linux NIC Drivers on FreeNAS

Tags: linux, drivers, freenas

I have a system with FreeNAS installed on.

With all the hardware, we have a HP 10Gbit NIC (NC522SFP) that needs to run. It is physically installed, but the system won't pick it up.

I've checked the FreeNAS 8 Hardware Compatibility list, to find that the card isnt there.

I have found the Drivers for multiple OS's at: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3913538&lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=3913537&taskId=135

Is there any way I can use any of these drivers on the FreeNAS OS?